# Error: array initializer must be an initializer list or wide string literal in C Merge Sort program

Tags: c, gcc, mergesort

I am pretty new to C and I am trying to make a basic merge sort program. when I compile this code (using GCC)

```
int join(int arrayA[],int aLength,int arrayB[],int bLength)
{
    int array[aLength+bLength];
    int uptoA = 0; int uptoB = 0;//the upto variables are used as the index we have reached
    while ((uptoA < aLength) && (uptoB < bLength))
    {
        if (arrayA[uptoA] < arrayB[uptoB])
        {
            array[uptoA+uptoB] = arrayA[uptoA];
            uptoA++;
        } else {
            array[uptoA+uptoB] = arrayB[uptoB];
            uptoB++;
        }//else
    }//while

    if (uptoA!=aLength)//if A is the array with remaining elements to be added
    {
        for (int i = uptoA+uptoB; i < aLength+bLength; i++)
        {
            array[i] = arrayA[uptoA];
            uptoA++;
        }
    } else {//if B is the array with elements to be added
        for (int i = uptoB+uptoA; i < aLength+bLength; i++)
        {
            array[i] = arrayB[uptoB];
            uptoB++;
        }//for
    }//else

    return array;
}//int join

int merge_sort(int array[],int arrayLength)
{
    if (arrayLength <= 1)
    {
        return array;
    }
    if (arrayLength == 2)
    {

        if (array[0] > array[1]) {return array;}//if it's fine, return the original array
        int returningArray[2]; returningArray[0] = array[1]; returningArray[1] = array[0]; //just makes an array that is the reverse of the starting array
        return returningArray;

    }

    int aLength = arrayLength/2;
    int bLength = arrayLength - aLength;
    //now I will create two arrays with each of the halves of the main array
    int arrayAunsorted[aLength];
    int arrayBunsorted[bLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < aLength; i++)
    {
        arrayAunsorted[i] = array[i];
    }
    for (int i = aLength; i < arrayLength; i++)//this goes from the end of arrayA to the end of the main array
    {
        arrayBunsorted[i] = array[i];
    }

    int arrayA[aLength] = merge_sort(arrayAunsorted,aLength);
    int arrayB[bLength] = merge_sort(arrayBunsorted,bLength);
    printf("I can get this far without a segmentation fault\n");

    return join(arrayA,aLength,arrayB,bLength);

}
```

I know that parts of this code are terrible and bad form, but I am going to fix that once I get the program to actually work. I'm very new to C, so I hope this isn't a stupid question.

Comment: There is no array initializers in this code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The error is presumably from `int arrayA[aLength] = merge_sort(arrayAunsorted,aLength);`

Comment: @Barmar aha.. missed this one

Comment: What do you expect this `int arrayA[aLength] = merge_sort(...` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
int arrayA[aLength] = merge_sort(arrayAunsorted,aLength);
```

First of all, you can't initialize an array by calling a function. As the error message says, you can only initialize an array using an initalizer list, like:

```
int arrayA[aLength] = {1, 2, 3};
```

or a string literal like:

```
char str[] = "abc";
```

Second, `merge_sort` doesn't even return an array, it returns `int`. It's not possible for a function to return an array in C, because arrays can't be assigned.

`join` is also incorrect. You have it declared to return `int`, but at the end it does:

```
return array;
```

When you return an array, it gets converted to a pointer, so it's actually returning `int*`, not `int`. But you can't return a pointer to a local array, because the memory of the array becomes invalid when the function returns.

Sorting functions should modify an array that's passed in to them by the caller. Either sort the array in place, or the caller should supply two arrays: one containing the input data and the other that should be filled in with the result.

I'm not going to try to rewrite all your code, it's too broken and I don't have the time. There are many resources showing how to implement merge sort in C.